# Creating feed using asp.net/.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, odata

I need to create a feed using asp.net. what technologies should I use ? I read somewhere that I need to use OData. Is it OdataServices or what. I am newbie. Please send me links or code samples.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this URL for creating RSS Feed in ASP.NET

[Create an RSS Feed in ASP.NET](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/asp/create-an-rss-feed-in-asp-net)

[RSS Feed using ASP.NET 2.0](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/RSSFeedEx.aspx)

### What is ODATA?

The Open Data Protocol (OData) is a Web protocol for querying and updating data that provides a way to unlock your data and free it from silos that exist in applications today. OData does this by applying and building upon Web technologies such as HTTP, Atom Publishing Protocol (AtomPub) and JSON to provide access to information from a variety of applications, services, and stores.

Comment: Do I need to use SCF services etc as wel ?